# Policy routing script for linux

Tags: networking, network-management, policy-routing

I am looking for some policy routing script for linux that isn't a part of a firewall, there are tools like shorewall and others but I prefer something more simple.

I only need a script that can set a per-service preference on one of my two upstream connections, and failover nicely when one of the connections is down.

So far I could only find a script called netsane that can be found at google code (http://code.google.com/p/netsane/) and it's more or less what I need but it looks a bit abandoned.
The script is largely based on [this tutorial from Larc](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html)
Does anyone know about more alternatives for this?

Comment: For anyone interested into this, I jumped into the code and made some contributions to the original source, it should work better with recent systems (I am trying it with debian squeeze)

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at [IGNWTools](http://code.google.com/p/ignw-tools/), which has some routing-policy for Chinese users, including ISP-based routes and anti-censorship routes, may help you as examples :)

Comment: After reading about that tool, it seems to me that it'd be complicated to adapt to my environment.

Comment: :( so hope you'll find something more appropriate